# AngularFire NormalizedCollection and order in firebasearray

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, firebase-util

I use AngularFire and Firebase-util library.
I would like to order a list in descending order from the last element to the first insert (in the bottom of this list).

```
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();

    var nc = new firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(
      ref.child('demandes/'+$state.params.chatId+'/reponses'), // main path
      [ref.child('reponses'), 'widget2'] // second path
    ).select('widget2.timestamp_inverse', 'widget2.intitule', 'widget2.commentaires', 'widget2.prix')
    .ref();

    $scope.reponses = $firebaseArray(nc);
```

I saw that to order depends on the main path ! But this main path is just a list of Firebase keys like -AZE4AZ4RQ4F53.
**How can I order this list like I want please ? Server-side or Client-side if needed ...**

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm forced to proceed like that : client-side 
With firebasearray, don't use `track by $index` or it will display an error like `"expected array but received ..."` and filter & order your array like you want :

```
 <ion-item  ng-repeat="reponse in filteredItems  = reponses  | orderBy:'FIELD_CHOSEN':true ">
```

If you have any suggestions to descending sort server-side, It will be nice to share with me :) 
Thank you